# What, if anything, does it mean when V is found as 0 during a Wilcox Signed Rank Test when using R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am running a pretest and posttest comparison for confidence scores. When I normally run this test, the v value is some number above 0. I then compare the given p-value to determine if it is significant.

This is the kind of output I am used to getting:

```
pretest = c (3,4,4,2,2,4,2,2,5,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,5,4,3,4,2,2,4,2,1,4,3)
posttest = c(4,5,4,5,4,5,3,6,5,6,4,2,5,2,4,5,3,3,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,4,5,5,4,3,6,5)

wilcox.test (pretest, posttest, paired = TRUE, exact = FALSE)


Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  pretest and posttest
V = 7.5, p-value = 2.461e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

**Current Questions**

My background is in education and not stats, so my knowledge can admittedly be brittle if I come across something I have not seen before.

I ran into a new situation today. My v was returned as 0.  See the following code:

```
pretest = c (2,3,3,4,4,1,2,3,2,4,4,2,2,5,3,3,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,4,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,4,2,3,4,2,3,2,5,2,1,3,2)

posttest = c (5,5,5,5,4,4,4,6,6,5,5,3,6,5,6,4,3,2,6,2,5,4,4,5,3,3,4,2,4,3,5,5,6,3,4,2,6,5,5,3,4,6,5)

wilcox.test (pretest, posttest, paired = TRUE, exact = FALSE)


Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  pretest and posttest
V = 0, p-value = 2.309e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

(1) My question is why was V returned as 0?  (2) Does that affect how I should interpret the p-value?  (3) What does the value of V mean? does/how does it matter?

Comment: @AER I appreciate you updating your question to clarify on your background. However, it can be *extremely* risky and questionable to use statistical methods if you don't understand what the corresponding test statistics denote and how to interpret results. I would usually advice meeting with a resident statistician or stats consultant to clarify on the suitability of methods and interpretation of results. The general advice aside, I have posted a simple example below which hopefully provides some background understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by @42-, I think your question has to do with a misunderstanding of what the `V` value denotes in a Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

To recap: The test statistic in a paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test (the `V` value) is the sum of the ranks of the pairwise differences `x - y > 0`.

Let's create some sample data to understand how `V` can be zero.

We draw samples from two normal distributions with different means.

```
set.seed(2018)
x <- rnorm(10, mean = 0)
y <- rnorm(10, mean = 5)
```

We now perform a paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test

```
wilcox.test(x, y, paired = TRUE, exact = FALSE)
#
#   Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
#
#data:  x and y
#V = 0, p-value = 0.005922
#alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

We first note how the p-value is very small, leading us to reject the null hypothesis that the ranks of the population means are the same. Since the samples `x` and `y` come from two normal distributions with very different means (`mean = 0` vs. `mean = 5`), this is hardly surprising. Furthermore, we note that the test statistic `V = 0`. Given the definition of the test statistic, this is means that there are no values `x > y`; we can confirm that this is indeed the case

```
any(x > y)
#[1] FALSE
```

For good measure, we can visualise the distribution of both samples

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(
    val = c(x, y),
    smpl = c(rep("x",length(x)), rep( "y", length(x))))) +
geom_histogram(aes(val, fill = smpl), bins = 30, position = "identity")
```

[image]